# How can I Split a Cell by Carriage Return and Append Values?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to split a cell by Carriage Return (3 cells to the left of my current cell) and concatenate 'AND' for all Carriage Returns, except the last one, and for the last one I want to concatenate 'YES'

Here is my VBA script.

```
CellSelect = ActiveCell.Value
CellAddress = ActiveCell.Address
Dim splitVals As Variant
arrLines = Split(Sheets("CP (POS) Tasklist").Range(CellAddress).Offset(0, -3).Value, Chr(10))

    For Each strLine In arrLines
        Debug.Print strLine
        Sheets("CP (POS) Tasklist").Range(CellAddress).Offset(0, 0).Value = strLine & Sheets("CP (POS) Tasklist").Range(CellAddress).Offset(0, -2).Value
    Next

End If
```

Here is a screen shot of my setup. Basically, I'm trying to concatenate what's in the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd cells, into the 4th cell.

[image]

I think I'm close.  I just can't seem to get it working correctly.

Thanks!!

Comment: A `For` loop would make it easier to tell when you got to the last element.

Answer (score 2):

Just `Replace` with `StrReverse` will workfine. No `For` or `Array` required.

```
Sub test()

   Dim strOrig  As String
   Dim strNew   As String


   'strOrig = Sheet1.Cells(1)
   strOrig = "a " & Chr(10) & " b " & Chr(10) & " c " & Chr(10)
   Debug.Print strOrig

'        a
'        b
'        c

   strNew = StrReverse(Replace(StrReverse(strOrig), Chr(10), StrReverse("YES"), , 1))
   strNew = Replace(strNew, Chr(10), "AND")

   Debug.Print strNew

   'a AND b AND c YES

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with this.

```
CellSelect = ActiveCell.Value
CellAddress = ActiveCell.Address
Dim splitVals As Variant
arrLines = Split(Sheets("CP (POS) Tasklist").Range(CellAddress).Offset(0, -3).Value, Chr(10))
arrLinesLast = UBound(arrLines)
    For Each strLine In arrLines
        If arrLinesLast <> 1 Then
            If arrLinesLast = 0 Then Exit Sub
            Debug.Print strLine
            Sheets("CP (POS) Tasklist").Range(CellAddress).Offset(0, 0).Value = Sheets("CP (POS) Tasklist").Range(CellAddress).Offset(0, 0).Value & " " & strLine & " " & Sheets("CP (POS) Tasklist").Range(CellAddress).Offset(0, -2).Value & Chr(10)
                arrLinesLast = arrLinesLast - 1
                Else
                Sheets("CP (POS) Tasklist").Range(CellAddress).Offset(0, 0).Value = Sheets("CP (POS) Tasklist").Range(CellAddress).Offset(0, 0).Value & " " & strLine & " " & Sheets("CP (POS) Tasklist").Range(CellAddress).Offset(0, -1).Value
                arrLinesLast = arrLinesLast - 1
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: OK. you don't need Offset(0, 0) in Range(CellAddress).Offset(0, 0).Value, because it is the range it self, so use Value directly : .Range(CellAddress).Value

Comment: Commenting and improved code spacing would make it easier for you to spot things mentioned by @D.O., as well as improving your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: split the cell value to an array and then add AND or YES if it is the last item in the array:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1")
    AppendAndYes rng
End Sub

Sub AppendAndYes(rngCell As Range)

    Dim varItems As Variant
    Dim lngIndex As Long

    'get lines by splitting on line feed
    varItems = Split(rngCell.Value, vbLf, -1, vbBinaryCompare)

    'loop through and add AND or YES
    For lngIndex = LBound(varItems) To UBound(varItems)
        If lngIndex < UBound(varItems) Then
            varItems(lngIndex) = varItems(lngIndex) & " AND"
        Else
            varItems(lngIndex) = varItems(lngIndex) & " YES"
        End If
    Next lngIndex

    'update cell value
    rngCell.Value = Join(varItems, vbLf)

End Sub
```